# Flask-SQLAlchemy raising: AttributeError: module 'psycopg2' has no attribute 'paramstyle'

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I'm running a generic (because I don't know enough to do anything beyond the basics) Flask-SQLAlchemy 3.0.2 setup on Python 3.10.

Not sure what happened, but at some point it started throwing this error every time I tried to query the db:
`AttributeError: module 'psycopg2' has no attribute 'paramstyle'`

I'm doing package management through poetry and SQLAlchemy 1.4.44 really wanted to use psycopg2 2.7, which I guess pre-dates `paramstyle`.

Answer (score 6):

I uninstalled psycopg2 (and removed its requirement from the poetry lock file), and installed psycopg2-binary 2.9.5 manually. Now it works.